# Targetting specific divs to return from AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax

When using an AJAX call, how can you target just specific divs.

I would like to return all divs with the class `.grid-item`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.domain.com/p20',
    success: function(html){
        console.log(html);  
    }
});
```

Comment: can you share a html sample

Comment: Note: cross domain calls would not be happen if you want to access the html data.